# Appstore approval of app with payment

Tags: app-store, appstore-approval

I'm developing an iOS app and soon will launch in AppStore. I have a payment method using Payture API. Is it possible to launch app in AppStore without D‑U‑N‑S Number(in Solo account)? Can any problems occur?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/support/enrollment/ - it will helps you